# Как обойти это исключения при работе с удалённой базой?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Что делаю не так ?

В случае отсутствия таблицы, получаю исключения.

Т.е. если получил исключение, хочу всё заново и заново долбиться, пока таблица не появится (ждать её) и если появилась, то забрать оттуда Id.

Таблица появляется через какое то время, но программа висит и не видит этих данных.

```
  private void PoluchitNomerPosledneiZapisi()
    {

        int r = 0;

        SqlCommand SelectDannieComand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Max(Id) FROM [ParserDB]", sqlConnection);

        try
        {
            string Id = SelectDannieComand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            PoluchitNomerPosledneiZapisi();
        }

            r = Convert.ToInt32(Id);

        BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(pisanina), r);

    }// Получить номер последней записи из БД
```

Comment: Как именно не видит? Продолжает падать с исключением? с каким именно? исключение меняется после реального появления таблицы в базе?

Comment: @PashaPash не падает и не получает данные, даже когда таблица и необходимые данные там есть.

Comment: @PashaPash, разобрался, r = Convert.ToInt32(Id); тоже выдавал исключение, просто код до него не доходил судя по всему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устраивать рекурсию в блоке `catch` очень плохая затея, так делать нельзя. В случае провала нужно просто возвращать результат сигнализирующий о безуспешности попытки, а не вызывать снова этот же метод, как вы делаете.

Вариант решения вашей проблемы.

```
int lastIndex = await Task.Run(() => GetLastIndex(10));

if (lastIndex < 0)
{
    //неудача
}

//успех
```

---

```
private int GetLastIndex(int maxAttempts)
{
    SqlCommand SelectDannieComand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Max(Id) FROM [ParserDB]", sqlConnection);

    int resultIndex = -1;

    string lastRecord;
    bool result = false;
    int attempts = 1;
    do
    {
        result = TryPoluchitNomerPosledneiZapisi(SelectDannieComand, out lastRecord);
        ++attempts;

    } while (!result || attempts <= maxAttempts);

    if (result)
    {
        resultIndex = Int32.Parse(lastRecord);
    }

    return resultIndex;
}

private bool TryPoluchitNomerPosledneiZapisi(SqlCommand selectDannieComand, out string lastRecord)
{
    try
    {
        lastRecord = selectDannieComand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        lastRecord = String.Empty;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернативу решению в принятом ответе, могу предложить изменить логику в запросе:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[ParserDB]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    SELECT MAX(Id) 
    FROM [ParserDB] AS a;
ELSE
SELECT 0;
```

В случае отсутствия данной таблицы в БД, запрос будет возвращать `0`. Остальную логику можно накручивать вокруг этого.

---

*К вопросу отношения не имеет, но замечу, что "правильнее" писать запросы к сущностям с указанием схемы, т.е. `SELECT * FROM schema.table`*

Comment: Тоже дело, пускай работает сервер СУБД.